# Horizontal margins for margin notes in the tufte classes

Tags: margins, book-design, tufte, marginnote

From the picture underneath you can see that the tufte class does not provide horizontal margins for the margin notes. Thus the margin notes can go beyond the `\textheigth`. Is that normal or is it a bug? How can I fix that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}


\begin{document}

TEST\footnote{Test note}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I experienced this circumstance to lead to margin figures flowing below the page area (e.g. if you add a margin figure right before the last sentence on a page).

Answer (score 3):

The package `marginfix` ([CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginfix)) is designed to deal with these issues. It properly aligns the the sidenotes. Just declare

```
\usepackage{marginfix}
```

in the preamble. Starting from Sep 2, 2013 it can deal with the `tufte-book` class. The newest version can be found on [github](https://github.com/shicks/marginfix).

Answer (score 2):

Probably this problem could be regarded as a bug, but in the other side, a side note (if you'll excuse the repetition) jumping to the next page or making a page break of the main text do not have sense at all. It would make more sense adjust the side note manually in these cases.

For notes occupying the bottom margin, instead of `\foonote` you can use `\marginnote` or `\sidenote` than have an optional offset argument, so you can control the vertical position as in the example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote[-3cm]{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[1]
\sidenote[][-3.5cm]{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```