# How to provide space for many or long sidenotes in tufte-book?

Tags: tufte, tufte-book

I use `tufte-book` and have too many sidenotes to fit on a page. In these cases, the sidenotes run longer than the bottom margins and are lost for the reader. How can the sidenote text, which does not fit on a page, made to continue on the next one?

I have seen [this attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624033/long-sidenotes-break-marginfix-or-how-to-make-breakable-sidenotes) which seems not to have been successful.

An MWE, where sidenotes 5, 6 and 7 are lost:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,nobib]  {tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}
\lipsum[6]\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}
%\clearpage
\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}
\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}
\lipsum[6]\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}\sidenote{\lipsum[4]}
\end{document}
```

My text is long and I would rather not add manually `\clearpage` at appropriate positions (as the commented out code suggests), which seems to produce an acceptable result. Other acceptable solutions would be to break the sidenote (or sidenotes) at the bottom of the page (to break at the next paragraph break) and continue on the next one.

How can I achieve an automatic solution?

Comment: As I understand it, side notes with the tufte classes cannot cross a page break. They must end on the very page where they begin. Here's an alternative approach (using KOMA script) that claims to have fixed this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295864/

Comment: @Ingmar - i fixed the link, thank you! I want to stay with the tufte style and and would accept a page break before the text where a non-fitting sidenote starts.

Comment: (1) Even in  tufte class, the margin is not a good place for large texts  (2) A note that is not side by side with the text of reference, is not longer a side note but a technical challenge only to torment readers (3) Do not include \clearpage. Yo can ajsut the vertical position of notes manuallys  (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123023/11604). Of course, do not fix notes positions until the final version, and is up to you ensure that you will not end with more notes that space in some page.

Comment: I experiment with a text where the main argument is in the main column and the extensions, comments and sources are in the margin.Thank you for the link to `marginfix` which is said to work with tufte classes now,  I plan to adjust eventually the margin width to reduce misalignement and then the tools from marginfix - once the text is close to ready. any other tools you can suggest?